# How to increase the cell size in occupancy grid properly?

Tags: ros, nav2d-exploration, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to change the cell size in the occupancy grid. I changed the resolution from 0.1 to 0.5.
But after this, my exploration algorithm fails at first step only. Any idea why this is happening?

I want to increase the cell size in order to decrease the number of frontiers at each step.

Image of costmap:
[image: image description]

Note: I made changes in mapper.yaml not in costmap
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221946/how-to-increase-the-cell-size-in-occupancy-grid-properly?/) by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be helpful if you could edit your question with a screenshot of the costmap you mention. With a 0.5 m cell size, there is a good chance that huge occupied cells prevent frontiers from being reachable.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-12-09**:
Sorry for the delayed response. I have attached the screenshot of my costmap.yaml. But, I made the changes in mapper.yaml not in costmap. Do you think that can be the reason?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-12-10**:
I mean a screenshot of the actual costmap visualized in rviz, not the settings. Also, in the screenshot the resolution is set to 0.05, not 0.5 as stated in your text.